# Help compiling banshee-telepathy-extension

Tags: banshee, compiling

I've made some changes to the [banshee-telepathy-extension](https://github.com/rebelliard/banshee-telepathy-extension/commit/2d8e0b94f1f5a38c9550dbf9a1e086ec371db1d8), but I can't get it to compile on Ubuntu 12.04, even after issuing a banshee

```
checking for BANSHEE_1_THICKCLIENT... no
configure: error: Package requirements (banshee-1-thickclient >= 1.5.3) were not met:`
```

Thanks in advance. :)

PS - Full stack below:

```
rafael@noir:~/workspace/banshee-telepathy-extension$ ./autogen.sh 
I am going to run ./configure with no arguments - if you wish 
to pass any to it, please specify them on the ./autogen.sh command line.
Running aclocal -I .  ...
Running automake --gnu  ...
Makefile.include:66: `pkglibdir' is not a legitimate directory for `SCRIPTS'
src/Makefile.am:181:   `Makefile.include' included from here
Running autoconf ...
Running ./configure ...
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... mawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking how to create a ustar tar archive... gnutar
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... yes
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking for gmcs... /usr/bin/gmcs
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
checking for MONO... yes
checking for GTK_SHARP_20... yes
checking for BANSHEE_1_THICKCLIENT... no
configure: error: Package requirements (banshee-1-thickclient >= 1.5.3) were not met:

No package 'banshee-1-thickclient' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables BANSHEE_1_THICKCLIENT_CFLAGS
and BANSHEE_1_THICKCLIENT_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extension you're trying to compile was designed in the days of Banshee 1.5.3. We are now up to Banshee 2.4.1 and the API is changed. `banshee-1` is now simply `banshee`, and the libraries are provided by the *banshee* package itself.

From a fresh git clone, change occurrences of `banshee-1` in `configure.ac` to `banshee` and `BANSHEE_1` to `BANSHEE`. That will let you get past this hurdle.